# saving in sharedpreferences take a lot of time

Tags: android

in my app to save configurations I do:

((Activity) context).getSharedPreferences("contentList", 0).edit()
                .putString("contentList", contentListString).commit();

((Activity) context).finish();

This takes a lot of time until the activity finishes. Is there a reason for this, and how to improve it?

Thanks, best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That involves:

1. reading the "contentList.xml" shared preferences file,
2. parsing the xml file
3. creating a "modified-values" map and add entries
4. applying the "modified-values" map into the shared preferences object
5. writing a new xml file (not overwriting "contentList.xml")
6. deleting "contentList.xml" and renaming the new file on step 5 into "contentList.xml"

If possible, do step numbers 1-2 on the application/activity load/initialization, do step 3 in the middle of your app lifetime, and do only 4-6 in the finishing activity.

Comment: Hi you are right. I even overdo it now. There are no more sharedpreferences. Writing to a file and reading it takes nearlx no time. Thanks.